# Partitioning Dask DataFrames from HDF files Behaviour

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am trying to compare two large datasets that are stored in `hdf5` files. However when using `dask.dataframe` it appears that it ignores the `chunksize` option as all `dd` objects have a `npartitions=1`.

```
a = dd.read_hdf(FLA, key='A')
b = dd.read_hdf(FLB, key='A')
```

produces an object

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
year    eiso3c  iiso3c  sitc3   value
npartitions=1                   
0   int64   object  object  object  float64
13414277    ... ... ... ... ...
Dask Name: read-hdf, 1 tasks
```

Therefore when I call either `(a == b).all().all().compute()` or `assert_eq(a, b)` the code seems to load both `a` and `b` datasets in full into memory.

Is this an issue with reading from `hdf5` as it appears to work when reading from `csv` files which produces a `dd` object with 7 partitions?

Comment: If you can create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of dask.dataframe ignoring the chunksize argument then I encourage you to [file a bug report](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new)